# Qweb : How can I use method sort() or function sorted() on Qweb?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I try to call  sort() method and sorted() function but it doesn't work.
Calling sorted() function :

```
<t t-set='data' t-value="{4: 'd', 3: 'c', 'b': 2, 'a': 1}"/>
<t t-set="list_key" t-value="sorted(list(data.keys()))"/>
<t t-esc="list_key"/>
```

But it gives me error like :

> Error to render compiling AST
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Calling sort() method:

```
<t t-set='data' t-value="{4: 'd', 3: 'c', 'b': 2, 'a': 1}"/>
<t t-set="list_key" t-value="list(data.keys()).sort()"/>
<t t-esc="list_key"/>
```

It gives no error but when i try to access one element of list_key, i get this error :

> Error to render compiling AST
>     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Can you help me? Thanky you.

Comment: [solved], creating the method inside the model then call it in qweb

Comment: Can you include your solution as a full answer (with your working code) in case anyone has the same issue in the future?

Comment: class TheModel(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'the.model'

    @api.multi
    def sort_key(self, k):
        return sorted(k)

Comment: omg, i don't know to format it inside comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you needed to create sort method inside your model definition, as `sorted` method is already provided to be applied on a recordset, can also be used inside qweb. For example, this line is taken from odoo community code:

```
<t t-foreach="move.move_line_ids.sorted(key=lambda ml: ml.location_id.id)" t-as="ml">
```

For more information on odoo ORM `sorted` method, you can read the official [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.sorted).

Comment: Because in my case, i don't use object from Odoo ORM but python variables that i pass through data in report. I try to use method sorted() but it doesn't work.